# Combine multiple less file using gulp and convert to css

Tags: gulp, less, gulp-less

I have multiple less files as you can see below:

**master.less**

```
@import "_a";
@import "_b";
```

**_a.less**

```
@x: 12px;
```

**_b.less**

```
body {
  font-size: @x;
}
```

And i using this gulp task to combine all above less file and then convert that to single css file:

```
gulp.task('less', function () {
    log('Compiling Less --> CSS');

    return gulp
        .src(config.less)
        .pipe($.plumber({errorHandler: swallowError}))
        .pipe($.sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe($.less())
        .pipe(concat('style.css'))
        .pipe($.autoprefixer())
        .pipe($.sourcemaps.write())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.tmp + '/css'));
});
```

But i get this error:

```
Error in plugin "gulp-less"
Message:
    variable @x is undefined in file /Users/me/Documents/Java/Projects/project/src/main/webapp/less/aa/_b.less line no. 2
Details:
    type: Name
    filename: /Users/me/Documents/Java/Projects/project/src/main/webapp/less/aa/_b.less
    index: 20
    line: 2
    callLine: NaN
    callExtract: undefined
    column: 13
    extract: body {,  font-size: @x;,}
    lineNumber: 2
    fileName: /Users/me/Documents/Java/Projects/project/src/main/webapp/less/aa/_b.less
```

How can o resolve this problem?

**NOTE**

I don't want to import **_a.less** in **_b.less**, i think gulp-less plugin should do this automatically when i imported **_a.less** in **master.less**.

Comment: Using what Less version?

Comment: "gulp-less": "^4.0.1"